# react native remove item from multidimentional array

Tags: react-native

I have an array in react native (using functional component) and I try to remove a specific item when clicking a button (each item holds their own button).

The array looks like this:

```
[ { img: 11, imgName: 'drums' },
{ img: 14, imgName: 'elektrisch' } ]
```

The img is the image file.

This is the code I use.

```
const StageItem = ({ item, onPress, style }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Image 
            key={item.name}
            style={styles.itemContainer}
            source={item.image}
            resizeMode='contain'
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const [ isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible ] = useState(false);
const [ finalArray, setFinalArray ] = useState([]);

const renderStgItem = ({item}) => {
    let img = item.image;
    let imgName = item.name;
    return (
        <StageItem
            item={item}
            onPress={() => {setFinalArray([...finalArray, {img, imgName}]);setIsModalVisible(false)}}
        />
    );
};
```

The following code I ty to remove a specific item from the array, but nothing happens:

```
const onRemove = item => {
    for (let i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
        if (finalArray[i] !== item.imgName) {
            setFinalArray(...finalArray, finalArray[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Anyone knows why?

**Updating with extra code**

I use the following code to map the array and show each image:

```
import {
    Menu,
    MenuOptions,
    MenuOption,
    MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';
import Gestures from 'react-native-easy-gestures';

finalArray.map((item, i) =>  (
    <Gestures 
        key={item.imgName}
        style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start',position: 'absolute', left: 20, top: 40}}
        onChange={(event, styles) => {
            styles.left <= 0 ? setXPos(false) : setXPos(true);
            styles.top <= 30 ? setYPos(false) : setYPos(true);
        }
    }
    draggable={{
        y: yPos,
        x: xPos
    }}
    >
        <TouchableHighlight onLongPress={() => setConextMenuOpen(true)} activeOpacity={0.7} underlayColor="transparent">
            <Image source={item.img} style={{height: 100,width: 100}} resizeMode='contain' />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Menu
            opened={contextMenuOpen}
            onBackdropPress={() => setConextMenuOpen(false)}
            rendererProps={{placement: 'top', anchorStyle: {backgroundColor: '#000000'}}}    
        >
            <MenuTrigger/>
            <MenuOptions>
                <MenuOption onSelect={() => onRemove(item)} >
                    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
                </MenuOption>
            </MenuOptions>
        </Menu>
    </Gestures>
))}
```

The remove function is inside the menuoption.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like:

```
const onRemove = ({ imgName }) => { // You can only pass imgName, no needs to pass full object.
    const newFinalArray = finalArray.filter(finalItem => finalItem.imgName !== finalName); 
   
    setFinalArray(newFinalArray);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't seem to do anything. I am updating my question with a bit more information.